# Issue opening IE using selenium cucumber

Tags: selenium

Facing below error when trying to open Internet Explorer using selenium and java?

Started InternetExplorerDriver server (64-bit)
        2.53.1.0
        Listening on port 47876
        Only local connections are allowed
        Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchSessionException: Unexpected error launching Internet Explorer. IELaunchURL() returned HRESULT 80070002 ('The system cannot find the file specified.') for URL 'http://localhost:47876/' (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
        Command duration or timeout: 77 milliseconds
        Build info: version: '3.4.0', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown'
        System info: host: 'LAPTOP-U09JTMGR', ip: '192.168.0.105', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_101'
        Driver info: driver.version: InternetExplorerDriver
            at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
            at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
            at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:215)
            at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:167)
            at org.openqa.selenium.remote.JsonWireProtocolResponse.lambda$new$0(JsonWireProtocolResponse.java:53)
            at org.openqa.selenium.remote.JsonWireProtocolResponse.lambda$getResponseFunction$2(JsonWireProtocolResponse.java:91)
            at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.lambda$createSession$22(ProtocolHandshake.java:365)
            at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(Unknown Source)
            at java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.tryAdvance(Unknown Source)
            at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEachWithCancel(Unknown Source)
            at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyIntoWithCancel(Unknown Source)
            at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(Unknown Source)
            at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(Unknown Source)
            at java.util.stream.FindOps$FindOp.evaluateSequential(Unknown Source)
            at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(Unknown Source)
            at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.findFirst(Unknown Source)
            at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:368)
            at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:159)
            at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:142)
            at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:82)
            at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:637)
            at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:250)
            at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:236)
            at org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver.run(InternetExplorerDriver.java:220)
            at org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver.(InternetExplorerDriver.java:212)
            at org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver.(InternetExplorerDriver.java:154)
            at test.Automation.App.main(App.java:17)

Comment: plz provide code how you are initializing the IE driver

Comment: Try to launch Internet Explorer through Selenium in normal mode and update the error stack trace in the question area. Thanks

Comment: Tried opening IE normally using below code still the same issue:   code used                             public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        
        WebDriver driver;
        System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", "C:\\Users\\anupa\\Selenium\\IEDriverServer_x64_2.53.1\\IEDriverServer.exe");
        driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
        driver.get("www.facebook.com");
    }